# Java - Game of Life - Trouble with displaying graphics

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, conways-game-of-life

I'm having a tough time finishing my Game of Life project. I have all of the algorithm's and functionality, but I cannot get the display to show. Anyone care to help? Thank you in advance!

Here is my (3) classes and the code for each:

Class ActiveFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ActiveFrame extends Frame {
//inherits from Frame class, but (Frame doesn't allow user to click out of extra window)
//Allows user to "x" out of window

//************
//Constructors
//************

public ActiveFrame(){
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    );

    setSize(300, 250);
    setTitle(getClass().getName());}
}
```

Class GoLWorldMainCS

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class GoLWorldMainCS extends ActiveFrame {

public static void main(String[] args){

    boolean cont;

    GoLWorldCS terrain = new GoLWorldCS();  

    terrain.setSize(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter rows: ")), 
                    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter cols: ")));
    terrain.setGenerations(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter generations: ")));

    if (terrain.getRow() > 60 ||
        terrain.getRow() < 1 ||
        terrain.getCol() > 60 ||
        terrain.getCol() < 1 ||
        terrain.getGenerations() < 1
        ){

        System.out.println("Error: Rows and Columns must be 1-60, and Generations must be greater than 0.");
    }

    else {

        terrain.setCellSize((600/terrain.getRow()), (600/terrain.getCol()));
        terrain.clearGrid();

        cont = true;
        while (cont == true){

            terrain.setCells(terrain.getC(), terrain.getR(), 1);

            terrain.setCells(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x-coordinate of live cell (999 to stop): ")), 
                    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter y-coordinate of live cell (0 to stop): ")),
                    Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter live row length (0 to stop)")));

            if(terrain.getR() == 999){
                cont = false;
            }

            else{

                if(terrain.getR() >= 0 && terrain.getR() <= terrain.getRow() &&
                    terrain.getC() >= 0 && terrain.getC() <= terrain.getCol() &&
                    terrain.getL() >= 0 && terrain.getL() <= (terrain.getRow() - terrain.getC() + 1)){

                    terrain.markAlive();
                    terrain.showDisplay();
                }

                else{ System.out.println("Entered coordinate out of bounds");}


            }
        }


    }


    }
   }
```

Class GoLWorldCS

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GoLWorldCS extends ActiveFrame {
int maxRow;
int maxCol;
int gen;
int buckets [][] = new int [maxRow][maxCol];
int r=0, c=0, l=1;
int xDist, yDist;

public GoLWorldCS(){    
}

public void clearGrid(){

    while (r<=maxRow-1){
        c=0;

        while (c<=maxCol-1){
            buckets[r][c] = 0;
            c=c+1;
        }

        r=r+1;
    }   
}

public void markAlive(){
    while (l > 1){
        buckets[r][c] = 1;
        c++;
        l--;
    }
}

public void showDisplay(Graphics g){

    r = 0;
     c = 0;
     g.setColor(Color.blue);

    while (r<=maxRow-1){
        c=0;

        while (c<=maxCol-1){
            if (buckets[r][c] != 0) {
            g.fillOval((c)*xDist + 50, (r)*yDist + 50, xDist, yDist);
            System.out.println(r + " " + c);
            }

            c=c+1;
        }

        r=r+1;
    }


}

public void setCellSize(int width, int height){
    this.xDist = width;
    this.yDist= height;
}

public void setSize(int maxR, int maxC){
    this.maxRow = maxR;
    this.maxCol = maxC;
}

public void setGenerations(int gens){
    this.gen = gens;
}

public void setCells(int R, int C, int L){
    this.r = R;
    this.c = C;
    this.l = L;
}

public int getRow(){
    return maxRow;
}

public int getCol(){
    return maxCol;
}

public int getGenerations(){
    return gen;
}

public int getR(){
    return r;
}

public int getC(){
    return c;
}

public int getL(){
    return l;
}
private static void main(String[] args)
{
    GoLWorldMainCS aframe = new GoLWorldMainCS ();

    aframe.setSize(700,700);
    aframe.setLocation(50,50);
    aframe.setTitle("Game of Life");
    aframe.show();
}
}
```

Comment: have you walked through the code?  Where do you expect the graphics to become visible?  What have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps [this article](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504) will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few issues and unnecessary things.  You were overriding `setSize()` of `Frame`, so it wasn't computing the size of the frame correctly.  You don't need the `ActiveFrame` class, you can just set the default close operation to exit on the frame.  Swing has more or less deprecated AWT, so you should extend `JFrame` instead of `Frame`. You can override the `paint()` method of `JFrame` and put your display logic in there, calling `terrain.repaint()` ends up calling the `paint()` method.  You were getting a `NullPointerException` in your display method because the size of the `buckets` did not match the `maxRow` and `maxCol` you were setting, I moved that to the constructor.

GoLWorldCS

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GoLWorldCS extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2833280938880400310L;
    int maxRow;
    int maxCol;
    int gen;
    int buckets[][];
    int r = 0, c = 0, l = 1;
    int xDist, yDist;

    public GoLWorldCS(int maxRow, int maxCol) {
        this.maxRow = maxRow;
        this.maxCol = maxCol;
        this.buckets = new int[maxRow][maxCol];
    }

    public void clearGrid() {
        while (r <= maxRow - 1) {
            c = 0;
            while (c <= maxCol - 1) {
                buckets[r][c] = 0;
                c = c + 1;
            }
            r = r + 1;
        }
    }

    public void markAlive() {
        while (l > 1) {
            buckets[r][c] = 1;
            c++;
            l--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        r = 0;
        c = 0;
        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        while (r <= maxRow - 1) {
            c = 0;
            while (c <= maxCol - 1) {
                if (buckets[r][c] != 0) {
                    g.fillOval((c) * xDist + 50, (r) * yDist + 50, xDist, yDist);
                    System.out.println(r + " " + c);
                }
                c = c + 1;
            }
            r = r + 1;
        }
    }

    public void setCellSize(int width, int height) {
        this.xDist = width;
        this.yDist = height;
    }

    public void setGenerations(int gens) {
        this.gen = gens;
    }

    public void setCells(int R, int C, int L) {
        this.r = R;
        this.c = C;
        this.l = L;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return maxRow;
    }

    public int getCol() {
        return maxCol;
    }

    public int getGenerations() {
        return gen;
    }

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }

    public int getL() {
        return l;
    }
}
```

GoLWorldMainCS

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GoLWorldMainCS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean cont;

        GoLWorldCS terrain = new GoLWorldCS(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter rows: ")), Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter cols: ")));
        terrain.setGenerations(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter generations: ")));

        terrain.setSize(700, 700);
        terrain.setTitle("Game of Life");
        terrain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        terrain.setVisible(true);

        if (terrain.getRow() > 60 || terrain.getRow() < 1 || terrain.getCol() > 60 || terrain.getCol() < 1 || terrain.getGenerations() < 1) {
            System.out.println("Error: Rows and Columns must be 1-60, and Generations must be greater than 0.");
        } else {
            terrain.setCellSize((600 / terrain.getRow()), (600 / terrain.getCol()));
            terrain.clearGrid();

            cont = true;
            while (cont == true) {
                terrain.setCells(terrain.getC(), terrain.getR(), 1);
                terrain.setCells(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter x-coordinate of live cell (999 to stop): ")), Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter y-coordinate of live cell (0 to stop): ")), Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter live row length (0 to stop)")));

                if (terrain.getR() == 999) {
                    cont = false;
                } else {
                    if (terrain.getR() >= 0 && terrain.getR() <= terrain.getRow() && terrain.getC() >= 0 && terrain.getC() <= terrain.getCol() && terrain.getL() >= 0 && terrain.getL() <= (terrain.getRow() - terrain.getC() + 1)) {
                        terrain.markAlive();
                        terrain.repaint();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Entered coordinate out of bounds");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Also, any advice on the loop to show the generations changing? Thank you again.

Comment: I didn't really understand the logic you were going for, so I ended up rewriting a lot of it.  Here's the source http://pastebin.com/yacH2w7m